# Function variable accessible in global scope

Tags: javascript, html

I was going through my Coursera assignment and I found that in my js, I used a variable called original_text to store my string and I was able to access it in my other function. I am confused as to how's this possible since the variable is in the local scope of my first function, how can it be accessed in my seconf function without it throwing a Reference error. I know it probably attaches itself to the window and becomes a global score variable but I want to know why. Can anybody explain it ?

Here's my js

```
function upDate(previewPic){
 
  var l = document.getElementById('image');
  var b = previewPic;
  const path= b.src;
  original_text = l.textContent; // variable being declared in function scope
  l.style.backgroundImage= "url("+path+")";
  l.innerHTML= previewPic.alt;
}

function unDo(){
        document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
        document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = original_text;//variable being accessed in another function
    }
```

and my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id = "image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>
    
    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"
    onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
    
    <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" 
    onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
    
    <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" 
    onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't declare it with `var`, `let`, or `const`, so it's a global variable.

Comment: …and if you had used [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), you would have gotten the expected exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS If you don't declare a variable it will be attached to the global scope, this is called `Implicit Globals`, you can read more about it: [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). So in the snippet below i'm just using `const` to declare the `original_text` constant

```
function upDate(previewPic){

  var l = document.getElementById('image');
  var b = previewPic;
  const path= b.src;
  const original_text = l.textContent; // variable being declared in function scope
  l.style.backgroundImage= "url("+path+")";
  l.innerHTML= previewPic.alt;
}

function unDo(){
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = original_text;
}
```

Further reading:
[Beware of unsafe implicit globals in JavaScript](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/beware-of-unsafe-implicit-globals-in-javascript-f370ccca8fdb?gi=3844dbe209ae#:%7E:text=If%20you%20assign%20a%20value,property%20of%20the%20window%20object.)